# Присваивание ячейки массива

Tags: java

```
int k=0;
char utu [] = textField3.getText().toCharArray();
k=utu[0];
textField1.setText(" k= \n"+k);
textArea1.setText(" utu[0]= "+utu[0]);
```

`textArea1` выдаёт то что и нужно нулевую ячейку, если я ввожу 1 то один и будет, а вот
`textField1`, выдает совсем другие значения напр. Если я ввожу 1 то результат дает 49, если 2 то 50 и т.д.

Почему `k` присваивается совсем другое непонятное значение, и можно ли как-то присвоить `k` ячейке массива, что бы `k` был типа `double`, а не `int`, как в моем примере?

Answer (score 3):

Когда Вы присваиваете значение переменной типа `char` переменной `int`, то в нее копируется значение символа в кодировке `Unicode`. Когда потом выдаете эту `int` в `String`, то там она преобразуется не в символ, а отображается как значение переменной `int`.

Выход - переменная `k` должна иметь тип `char`.

Comment: В int ляжет значение в UTF-16. Но объяснение и решение всё равно валидные.

Comment: Да, спасибо за замечание. Мое сишное воспитание.

Comment: Мне дальше нужно будет делать с переменой k математические операции,
k типа char не подходит, Другиг вариантов нету?

Comment: Когда даете k в строку, преобразуйте ее в char:  (char) k

Answer (score 2):

В переменной `k` хранится код символа.

Comment: а как можно присвоить значение ячейки массива?
Напишите плис Как уладить это на примере

Comment: как-то так (да не возгневаются гуру, если что не так):

    int k = Integer.valueOf( new String( new char[] {utu[0])} );

Comment: Все ок, все работает (только дужки перепутал). Спасибо!!!

    int k = Integer.valueOf( new String( new char[] {utu[0]}) );

Comment: Это называется "ехать в Астрахань через Архангельск"

Comment: Не спорю. Просто вопрос стоял

> а как можно присвоить значение ячейки массива?

вот конкретно на него и был дан ответ :) возможно и не самый оптимальный.

Comment: Если известно, что в "ячейке массива" десятичная цифра, то самое простое:  int k = utu[0]-'0';

Comment: Интересное свойство!

Comment: Посмотрите на числовые коды символов и загадок станет меньше.

Comment: @avp, для меня числовые коды символов не являются загадкой :) но на это свойство никогда не обращал внимание :) так что спасибо за то, что открыли глаза :)

Comment: Тогда уж вместо 

    int k = Integer.valueOf( new String( new char[] {utu[0])} );

надо

    int k = Integer.valueOf(new String(utu, 0, 1));

Answer (score 2):

Интуиция подсказывает мне, что Вы ищете:

```
int k;
try {
   k = Integer.valueOf(textField3.getText().trim());
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
   ....
}
```

Вы ведь хотите взять **число**, которое вводится в поле какой-то формы ?

Comment: Сдается мне, это попытка сделать калькулятор или что-то вроде того )

Comment: Да, вы правы, это программа для вычисление различных уравнений, где коэффициент уравнения вводятся как число, так и символы, например, `t+1`, которое будет в дальнейшем вычисляться.

Comment: Тогда вам стоит почитать материал о грамматиках и парсерах.

Comment: Думаю, лучше не надо..